# error while connecting kivy app with bluetooth.

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, kivy

i'm using windows 7 and python 2.7, i'm trying to connect my kivy app with bluetooth but i'm getting this error message. please explain.

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bluetooth.py", line 15, in <module>
    BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\jnius\reflect.py", line 154, in autoclass
  File "jnius\jnius_export_func.pxi", line 25, in jnius.find_javaclass (jnius\jnius.c:16263)
jnius.JavaException: Class not found 'android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter'*
```

Comment: [This](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.utils.html#kivy.utils.platform) little trick will prevent your app to run java stuff on windows. Make more `if`s for each api if you plan to use bluetooth on all kivy supported platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're showing is what you'd run on Android to access the BluetoothAdapter class. Windows doesn't have this (or any of the rest of the Android API), so it fails.

If you want to use bluetooth on windows, find a windows platform specific way of doing it (this is unlikely to involve pyjnius).

Comment: how do I get access to Android API then using pyjnius ? i followed some tutorials where i find that by pyjnius package i will be able to use java API, which includes the bluetooth setup too. but this is showing error so please explain.

Comment: You can use the Android java api when running on android, not when running on windows. You need to build your app as an apk.